# How to view layers by data source in QGIS 3?

Tags: layers, qgis-3

Is there a tool or panel in QGIS 3 that allows a user to view the map layers by data source? Similar to the `List By Source` view in the ArcMap Table of Contents?
[image]

I thought I had come across it, but now I can't find it. Perhaps I dreamt it up or perhaps I'm searching with the wrong vocabulary.

Does this capability exist in the core QGIS software? Or a plugin?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the list of the layers in the current project with a PyQGIS script like this:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
lnames = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
print(lnames)
```

To access the PyQGIS console: `Plugins` -> `Python Console`

this produces a list of layers in the current project:

`['GoogleSat', 'MyPointsLayer', 'Roads', 'House_numbers']`

(Not by source though)

Other scripts you might find useful can be found in the *PyQGIS Cookbook*:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html#layers

Answer (score 3):

The Change Data Source Plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/changeDataSource/ will give you a list of all the layers in the file and their locations.

Comment: The plugin is nice and very usefull but it also just lists the layers and source and does not  s o r t  the layers by source

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to view the layer sources of saved and memory layers:

```
for count, layer in enumerate(QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()):
    uri_component = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().decodeUri(layer.dataProvider().name(), layer.publicSource())
    print(f'{count}. {layer.name()}')
    try:
        print(uri_component['path'], "\n")
    except KeyError:
        print(" I don't know what this layer's path is.. likely a memory layer.")
```